# Creating a directed acyclic graph from undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

In how many ways can i direct an undirected graph so that it is acyclic?

You are given two integers n(the number of vertices) and m(the number of edges).
0<=m<=n*(n-1)/2 The next m lines contain two integers v1 and v2 (1<=v1, v2<=n) denoting a edge between vertices v1 and v2.

no self loops
, it isn't a multigraph

In how many ways can I direct the graph(give orientation to each edge) such that the newly created directed graph is acyclic

I don't even know where to start, I've counted the cycles in the undirected graph, hoping it would lead me somewhere, but that didn't help. I tried searching on google and nothing appeared on the subject.

Comment: [CEOI 2019 Mirror Day 2 (problem A) tutorial](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/68748)

Comment: @user202729 I'm not able to open your link, can you elaborate?